# Unable to access fromJson function for freezed custom model

Tags: flutter, flutter-freezed, build-runner

I have declared a custom freezed model in a flutter web project as follows:

```
@freezed
class User with _$User {
  const factory User({
    required int id,
    required String name,
    required Address address,
    @Default(null) Contact? contact,
  }) = _User;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
}
```

The models for `Address` and `Contact` are as follows:

```
@Freezed()
class Address with _$Address {
  const factory Address({
    required String type,
    required String address,
    required String subDistrict,
    required String district,
    required String state,
    required String country,
    required String pincode,
    Coordinates? coordinates,
  }) = _Address;

  factory Address.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AddressFromJson(json);
}

@Freezed()
class Coordinates with _$Coordinates {
  const factory Coordinates({
    required double latitude,
    required double longitude,
  }) = _Coordinates;

  factory Coordinates.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CoordinatesFromJson(json);
}
```

```
@Freezed()
class Contact with _$Contact {
  const factory Contact({
    @Default([]) List<String> email,
    @Default([]) List<String> mobile,
    @Default([]) List<String> landline,
    @Default([]) List<String> fax,
  }) = _Contact;

  factory Contact.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ContactFromJson(json);
}
```

Now, the issue is that when I try to create an instance of this model from json, it throws the following error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'user$.User.fromJson'
```

However, this is not happening for all the models in the project. I am facing this issue only for the aforementioned one.

I tried not setting `@Default(null)` as well but the same issue arises. I have ensured that the data being passed is json and not a String.

What could be the issue here?

```
Flutter 3.7.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 62bd79521d (2 weeks ago) • 2023-03-30 10:59:36 -0700
Engine • revision ec975089ac
Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1

dependencies:
  freezed_annotation: ^2.2.0
  json_annotation: ^4.8.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.3.3
  freezed: ^2.3.2
  json_serializable: ^6.6.1
```

Just found that this happens in debug mode. Runs fine in release mode. This is the stacktrace:

```
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50   <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1660:54                                 runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                           handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                           handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                           _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 567:5                            [_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 640:7                            callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                     _microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                      _startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15  <fn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the part statement `yourfile.g.dart`

Make sure that you have successfully run the `build_runner`.´

Try running with `--delete-conflicting-outputs`

If you need to serialize/deserialize nested freezed classes, you also have to add `@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)` or set `explicit_to_json` inside your build.yaml

`@Default(null)` can/should be removed. It adds nothing.

### Edit

I've just copied your models, succesfully generated all files, created models, serialized and deserialized it. Works fine in release mode and debug mode.

I removed the `@Default(null)` on contact.

The models:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'temp.freezed.dart';
part 'temp.g.dart';

@freezed
class User with _$User {
  const factory User({
    required int id,
    required String name,
    required Address address,
    Contact? contact,
  }) = _User;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
}

@Freezed()
class Address with _$Address {
  const factory Address({
    required String type,
    required String address,
    required String subDistrict,
    required String district,
    required String state,
    required String country,
    required String pincode,
    Coordinates? coordinates,
  }) = _Address;

  factory Address.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AddressFromJson(json);
}

@Freezed()
class Coordinates with _$Coordinates {
  const factory Coordinates({
    required double latitude,
    required double longitude,
  }) = _Coordinates;

  factory Coordinates.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CoordinatesFromJson(json);
}

@Freezed()
class Contact with _$Contact {
  const factory Contact({
    @Default([]) List<String> email,
    @Default([]) List<String> mobile,
    @Default([]) List<String> landline,
    @Default([]) List<String> fax,
  }) = _Contact;

  factory Contact.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ContactFromJson(json);
}
```

Using the models here:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:console_app/temp.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  var user = User(
    id: 42,
    name: 'name',
    contact: Contact(
      email: ['test@email.com'],
      fax: ['0123-456789'],
      landline: ['0246-8101214'],
      mobile: ['0135-791113'],
    ),
    address: Address(
        type: 'type',
        address: 'address',
        subDistrict: 'subDistrict',
        district: 'district',
        state: 'state',
        country: 'country',
        pincode: 'pincode',
        coordinates: Coordinates(
          latitude: 12.34567,
          longitude: 98.7654,
        )),
  );
  var jsonData = jsonEncode(user.toJson());
  var file = File('user.json');
  file.writeAsStringSync(jsonData);
  var readUserFromFile = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(file.readAsStringSync()));
  assert(user == readUserFromFile);
  print(readUserFromFile);
}
```

This is the resulting json file:

```
{
  "id": 42,
  "name": "name",
  "address": {
    "type": "type",
    "address": "address",
    "subDistrict": "subDistrict",
    "district": "district",
    "state": "state",
    "country": "country",
    "pincode": "pincode",
    "coordinates": { "latitude": 12.34567, "longitude": 98.7654 }
  },
  "contact": {
    "email": ["test@email.com"],
    "mobile": ["0135-791113"],
    "landline": ["0246-8101214"],
    "fax": ["0123-456789"]
  }
}
```

and this is the resulting print:

```
User(id: 42, name: name, address: Address(type: type, address: address, subDistrict: subDistrict, district: district, state: state, country: country, pincode: pincode, coordinates: Coordinates(latitude: 12.34567, longitude: 98.7654)), contact: Contact(email: [test@email.com], mobile: [0135-791113], landline: [0246-8101214], fax: [0123-456789]))
```

Comment: I have done that. The build runner completes the build successfully. As I said, I have multiple models in the project where I am not facing the issue. It happens only for this one. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Are address and contact also freezed models?

Comment: Yes. I tried passing the json to these address and contact seperately and they work fine.

Comment: Ok, I just found that this isn't happening when I run in release mode. Only on debug mode. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Should be no difference between debug and release mode. Sounds like something is cached. See my edit and try again.

Comment: I did this and even tried deleting the cache folder and reinstalled the dart sdk. The issue still persists.

Comment: I cannot see anything else that is wrong. You'll have to present your entire files containing the User, Address and Contact models so that the problem can be replicted by "us".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have added the other models in the question.

Comment: Hmmm. I still am unable to get around this issue. Must be that my system is corrupted probably/ Will try resetting it. Thank you so much for your help.